# How to provide a list of WiFi ID's and Passwords to Connect to Various WiFi Routers

Tags: networking, wifi, boot, pi-3, raspbian-jessie

What I want to do is that for a set number of locations of my choosing, I would like to provide a list of WiFi ID's and corresponding Passwords that my raspberry pi 3 can cycle through in an attempt to connect to detected wifi routers until a connection has been established upon boot. Is there any way to do this? Would it be possible for even open wifi routers such as coffee shops or school campuses? Thank you and I greatly appreciate your guys' input, thoughts, and advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using `Raspbian` (you should specify in question) You can put multiple networks in `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`. Mine is:-

```
country=AU
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
    ssid="PiNET"
    psk=""
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
        priority=50
}

network={
    ssid="BNET"
    psk=""
    scan_ssid=1
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    priority=40
}

network={
    ssid="Blue Marlin WiFi"
    psk=""
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir! That is exactly what I was trying to learn. I will have to figure out everything in the config file. Interested in the "priority" term.